# How does the decoder know when to display the next Frame in streaming video?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264

If I am streaming (I mean, simply broadcasting raw data over UDP sockets) a H.264 stream, how does the decoder decide at what FPS it should display the video?

I know that every once in a while it displays a frame that it receives, but how does it decide when the time is up for a frame and it is time to display the next one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playback framerate is determined by timecodes embedded in the transport stream, or in the video bitstream itself. Each frame is packaged with  a display time (either relative or absolute) and this is used to decide how long each frame should remain on the screen.